# Displaying Unicode characters in Android using localization

Tags: android, unicode, localization, unicode-string

I am writing a simple application where I want to display some Unicode characters as words, say in Kannada/Hindi/German or such kind of languages rather than English.

I tried placing the respective font in the assets folder and setting it to the textview like this:

```
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "some_font.TTF");
  tv.setTypeface(font);
```

But it didn't work. Also referred some other examples, but I am not able to replicate it in my application.

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/how-to-make-an-android-device-to-display-complex-rendering-of-indic-characters) link.It has explained in detail that how to use the different language fonts in app.

There is have a lot of problem in tamil unicode font, because english have only 26 characters but in tamil we have more than 365 characters( sorry for wrong history i dont know that perfectly).Refer this [link](http://irukaveandiyathutha.blogspot.in/2012/04/easy-to-enable-tamil-fonts-in-android.html).

Comment: So,that means I need to route the phone and add the font to the phone?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get my 50% of the task done with this example

http://android.programmerguru.com/android-localization-at-runtime/

But I still have doubt that, suppose if the phone doesn't support Hindi or Tamil, how to add the font so that it displays these languages.

I know rooting the phone and placing the font there is one solution, but apart from that are there any methods to achieve this?